# Trouble using strcpy with character array and string values in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, string, character, strcpy

I am taking a course in Objective-C and was told to "Create a character array called names. Populate the array with five first names. Use the strcpy command to copy the string values in to the array."

I coded my solution to this but it keeps giving me errors. I have been playing with this code for 35 minutes now and still cannot get it to run or be error free.

Here is the code that I created in response to the instructions above:

```
  char names[24];
  strcpy (names, "Jeff", "Steve", "Stan", "Mike", "Travis");
```

I do not understand why it won't work properly because I have allocated the correct number of char indexes with 24 and feel that I have used the strcpy function correctly as well.

Here are the errors that I'm getting in xcode:

1. Expected ";" after expression - wants to place ; after strcpy
2. Too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation.
3. Extranneous ")" before ";" - Wants me to replace ")" with quotes "

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not a correct use of [`strcpy`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/string.h/strcpy). There should be a compiler error telling you that strcpy expects 2 parameters, not 6.

Comment: Is this the C section of the Objective-C class? It isn't using any Objective-C language features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strcpy` takes only two arguments.

You should do as: `strcpy (names, "Jeff");`

---

I think you want to store 5 names in an array. For this you need to create a 2D-array.

```
char names[5][24];
```

And then use:

```
strcpy (names[0], "Jeff");        
strcpy (names[1], "Steve");
...//etc
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. Is there an alternate way to do it without a 2D array, or is this the only way? I find it strange that my instructor didn't include a lesson on 2d arrays before giving me this question.

Comment: No other way. As your requirement is to populate 5 names. Names means multiple characters(which is array!!!) and 5 names means array of array hence a 2D-Array.